# 14.04 Lubuntu -- Choosing Keyboard Layout on LightDM

Tags: keyboard, lubuntu, lightdm, keyboard-layout

I added `indicators=keyboard` to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf` and a keyboard chooser appears, but I cannot for the life of me get it to list multiple keyboard layouts.  I am on Lubuntu 14.04.  Have tried using `unity-control-center` to add a layout.  Adding a layout to my ibus.  Tried forcing the gsettings on the lightdm user (they seem to get regenerated / overwritten on reboot).  I did this to my `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
XKBMODEL="pc105,pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="us,us"
XKBVARIANT="dvorak,"
```

If I invert the order of those pairs then I get QWERTY only option in lightdm, and if I have them like this I get the Dvorak only option in the drop-down, but I still cannot find a way to make it list both of them.

I have multiple users on this computer that each prefer to type passwords with a different layout, so I really need this feature.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make lightdm-gtk-greeter show a keyboard layout menu in the top right panel. One way to do it is to create a file in the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.d` folder and list a custom selection of indicators to be shown:

```
$ cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf.d/50-modify-indicators.conf
[greeter]
indicators = ~host;~spacer;~session;~language;~layout;~a11y;~clock;~power
```

(The `~layout` option represents the keyboard layout menu.)

One disadvantage is that the menu lists all available (i.e. quite a few) keyboard layouts, so even if you can switch keyboard layout that way, it's not very convenient.

Comment: @Anwar: To be honest I'm not quite happy with the solution; there ought to be something better.

Comment: If you read my question you'll note I have the keyboard indicator added already. I want to know how to get this indicator to list multiple layouts.

Comment: @singpolyma: You wrote that you added `indicators=keyboard` which does not sound right to me. So maybe you should try the above?

Comment: using ~layout instead shows nothing. I'm on 14.04 -- using keyboard works, but only shows a single layout (the default xkb option)

Comment: @singpolyma: Tested my answer on 14.04 and can confirm that `~layout` doesn't work there for me either. Then I tested with `keyboard`, which works for me on both 14.04 and 16.04; actually it works better, because the list of options consists of actually added layouts, not all the available ones. I have only tested on Ubuntu, though, not Lubuntu. Guess I should edit my answer, but haven't time to do it right now.

Comment: Great! So how were those layouts actually added? I guess on Ubuntu it's maybe different than Lubuntu in this regard, hmm...

Comment: @singpolyma: Basically it seems to be what's in `/etc/default/keyboard` plus what the users added as gsettings. And yes, possibly Ubuntu and Lubuntu differ. One way to shed some light would be that you run the command: `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources`